# Flexigrid doesn't display data in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, flexigrid

I have a Flexigrid getting JSON data from a WebService I created. While debugging, I can see, the GetData() web method is being called and the method returns valid JOSN data. But it does not display in the flexigrid. Here goes the code snippet I am using:

```
 $(document).ready(new function ()
{
   $("#flex1").flexigrid
  (
    {
        url: "FlexigridDataService.asmx/GetData",
        dataType: 'json',
      //  method: 'GET',            
        colModel: [
            {
                display: 'MetaDataKey', name: 'MetaDataKey', width: 600, sortable:     true, align: 'center'
            },
            {
                display: 'MetaDataValue', name: 'MetaDataValue', width: 600, sortable: true, align: 'center'
            }
        ],
        searchitems: [
            { display: 'MetaDataKey', name: 'MetaDataKey', isdefault: true },
            { display: 'MetaDataValue', name: 'MetaDataValue' }
        ],
        onError: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("ERROR!!!" + + errorThrown)
        },
        sortname: "MetaDataKey",
        sortorder: "asc",
        usepager: true,
        title: 'Meta-Data..',
        useRp: true,
        rpOptions:[50,100,150,200,250],
        rp: 100,
        showTableToggleBtn: false,
        width: 1200,
        //onSubmit: addFormData,
        height: 500,            
        singleSelect: false
    }
);
```

});

GetData() gets the data from MS-SQL database and form JSON object. Am I missing anything?? really annoyed.. any help is appreciated..

Thanks,
DK

Comment: 1) you have a syntax error onError - you have 2 plus signs. It should be alert("ERROR!!!" + errorThrown);
2) what browser are you using?
3) could you please provide the JSON data sample that  you receive? - You can do it by using Dev Tools of a browser (press F12 in IE,Chrome). Go to Network tab, click on the "FlexigridDataService.asmx/GetData" request, and it should display the json data returned.